# CSS Centered Image effecting screen width, mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I’m having some issues with styling my header image while using bootstrap and I’m not sure where else to take this.  The image has always been centered however there is been a left-right scroll at the bottom of the page.  It was annoying, but it was not an issue as it worked fine on mobile devices.  Now, with some recent updates the website does not appear correctly on my phone (cache clears I guess) which is a problem.  I’ve identified what’s causing the issue but I do not know enough about CSS to correct it with bootstrap and mobile devices.  The website is SamsSocial.com to see the live example of it which may make it easier to debug.  Any help that can be given would be much appreciated.  Thank you

```
<style>
.header_img {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -950px;
}  
</style>
<script>
    function preload(arrayOfImages) {    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;     });}
    preload([
        "{{ asset('images/header_thin/header2-center_thin_01.png') }}",
        "{{ asset('images/header_thin/header2-center_thin_02.png') }}",
        "{{ asset('images/header_thin/header2-center_thin_03.png') }}",
        "{{ asset('images/header_thin/header2-center_thin_04.png') }}",
    ]);
</script>

<body>
<div class="header_img hidden-print">
    <table width="1900" height="98" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><img src="{{ asset('images/header_thin/header2-center_thin_01.png') }}" width="840" height="98" alt=""></td>
            <td><a href="{{ url('/') }}"><img src="{{ asset('images/header_thin/header2-center_thin_02.png') }}" width="238" height="59" alt=""></a></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><img src="{{ asset('images/header_thin/header2-center_thin_03.png') }}" width="822" height="98" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><img src="{{ asset('images/header_thin/header2-center_thin_04.png') }}" width="238" height="39" alt=""></td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
```

EDIT

Two edits have been useful in making the issue better, but my problem is not fully resolved. Everything is fine on the desktop viewed in all sizes, but when I pull up on my phone, it allows the zoomout i believe on the margin-left to the -950 (which i think is why it's to the right). If anyone knows how to fix this, it would be much appreciated. I'm also not sure how to do combine the pictures easily in any way other than a table

```
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.header_img {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -950px;
    width:1900px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Tables are not for layot/styling. Use approriate markup

Comment: I don't see where Bootstrap is being used in your sample code. The main purpose of Bootstrap is to provide a flexible, responsive grid to layout your website... however you are using `<table>` for layout, which is like anti-responsive/anti-Bootstrap. You should only use `<table>`'s to display data. You will have responsive issues with your setup

Comment: okay.. i have this image where which i sliced... i've never seen an image sliced differently so i have to look up how to do that. i didn't include the general bootstrap css as it's a significant amount. i actually don't know the proper way to format this in css. is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "max-width" or min-width, in order to make this picture responsive. you can define width: 100%, and then define the max-width and min-width.
I think it will fix it.